# Find & Replace Matching Entire Cell Contents in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace

I have the script to find '-' and replace with '' in 2 columns H:I that worked but How to modify to replace "Matching Entire Cell Contents"

Ex:

Column H = 123-456

Column I = -

and I want result:

Column H = 123-456

Column I =

```
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'), true);
  const range = spreadsheet.getDataRange();
  rang = spreadsheet.getRange('H:I').activate();
  const textFinder = range.createTextFinder('-');
  const allOccurrences = textFinder.replaceAllWith('');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to match entire cell that will be replaced. Please see code below:

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'), true);
const range = spreadsheet.getDataRange();
rang = spreadsheet.getRange('H:I').activate();
const textFinder = range.createTextFinder("^-$").useRegularExpression(true);
const allOccurrences = textFinder.replaceAllWith('');
```

This transformed this:

[image]

To this:

[image]